# Omni-Channel Beta: Pop Case using Pre-Chat form

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, omnichannel

Currently we have a Pre-Chat form that was working with just live agent but is not longer working when we enable omni-channel. The Pre-Chat form lookup up an Account, Product, and then associated the product and account to a case, then popped the case.

Sadly the pre-chat form is no longer popping the case, and the case does not seem to be getting created, it is unclear to me why this is happening, so I am hoping someone can help.

Bellow is a snipper of my pre-chat code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="CaseId" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Case" value="true" />
<input type= "hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Account" value="Case,AccountId" />
<input type= "hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Product_vod__c" value="Case,Product_MVN__c" />
```

Does Omni-Channel do something different that would cause the above code to work fine without it, but break with it?

Answer (score 0):

We actually had the same problem - Live Agent works fine. When you enable Omni-Channel Routing for the Live Agent Button, suddenly the Transcript is created in a Queue, and being routed to the Agent; which I think is the root of the problem - if you are also routing cases, how does it know to route the Live Chat Transcript AND the associated record to the same person as the same time, taking into account capacity and other Omni settings.

There were three major changes in winter 17 that could attribute to this:

1. New page layouts
2. New linkage sidebar widget and removal of paperclip
3. Omni Enabled Queue Based Routing

We had to do a few things to get around this.

1. Update our pre-chat form to define the field value and perform prechat.save into a custom field on the Transcript.
2. Build a trigger that takes the values stored from item 1, and either build or populate the values on matches
3. We also found that even after you complete the chat, the values are still being purged - the pre-chat form values stay, but the linked records were being automatically cleared.  Modified #2 to put them back where we want them.